# Javascript code not running on PUG/Jade file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm following this tutorial to implement a tic tac toe game using socket.io:
https://ayushgp.github.io/Tic-Tac-Toe-Socket-IO/ .

But I also want to use a login system.

When the user logs in, it successfully goes to this page (I converted html to pug), located on /views/game.pug

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Tic Tac Toe
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/main.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/node_modules/skeleton-css/css/skeleton.css')
  body
    .container
      .menu
        h1 Tic - Tac - Toe
        h3 How To Play
        ol
          li Player 1 Create a new game by entering the username
          li
            | Player 2 Enter another username and the room id that is displayed on first window.
          li Click on join game. 
        h4 Create a new Game
        input#nameNew(type='text', name='name', placeholder='Enter your name', required='')
        button#new New Game
        br
        br
        h4 Join an existing game
        input#nameJoin(type='text', name='name', placeholder='Enter your name', required='')
        input#room(type='text', name='room', placeholder='Enter Game ID', required='')
        button#join Join Game
      .gameBoard
        h2#userHello
        h3#turn
        table.center
          tr
            td
              button#button_00.tile
            td
              button#button_01.tile
            td
              button#button_02.tile
          tr
            td
              button#button_10.tile
            td
              button#button_11.tile
            td
              button#button_12.tile
          tr
            td
              button#button_20.tile
            td
              button#button_21.tile
            td
              button#button_22.tile
    .container
    script(src='/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
    script(src='/js/main2.js')
```

That works fine. But when I click the button with id #new, nothing happens. 
This is the error I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwrVc.png .

This is the relevant part of main2.js, located on /public/js/main2.js:

```
  $('#new').on('click', () => {
    const name = $('#nameNew').val();
    if (!name) {
      alert('Please enter your name.');
      return;
    }
    socket.emit('createGame', { name });
    player = new Player(name, P1);
  });
```

EDIT:

**Files' locations:**

**main.css** on /public/css/main.css

**skeleton.css** on /node_modules/skeleton-css/css/skeleton.css

**jquery.min.js** on /node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js

**socket.io.js** on /node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js

**main2.js** on /public/js/main2.js

app.js (only relevant parts are shown):

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.use(express.static('.'));
//Load View engine
app.engine('pug', require('pug').__express);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

//Set public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//This get request is sent after the user logs in. It works fine
    app.get('/users/game', function(req, res) {
        res.render('game', {
          title:'Game'
      });
    });

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
//See full code here:https://github.com/ayushgp/tic-tac-toe-socket-io/blob/master/index.js
}

let articles = require('./routes/articles');
let users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/articles', articles);
app.use('/users', users);
```

Also, my main2.js file is identical to this one: https://github.com/ayushgp/tic-tac-toe-socket-io/blob/master/main.js

EDIT2:
Full app.js code (the relevant part is the get request to users/game:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const config = require('./config/database');
const passport = require('passport');

let rooms = 0;

app.use(express.static('.'));

mongoose.connect(config.database, {
  useMongoClient: true
});
let db = mongoose.connection;

//Check connection
db.once('open', function(){
  console.log('Connected to MONGOdb')
});

//Check for DB errors
db.on('error', function(err){
  console.log(err);
});

//Bring in models
let Article = require('./models/article');

//Load View Engine
app.engine('pug', require('pug').__express);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// Boddy parser middlware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

//Set public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Express Session Middleware
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: false }
}));

//Express Messages Middleware
app.use(require('connect-flash')());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

//Express Messages Middleware
app.use(expressValidator());

//Passport Config
require('./config/passport')(passport);
//Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('*', function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});


//Home ROute
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  Article.find({}, function(err, articles){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render('index', {
        title:'Articles',
        articles: articles
      });
    }
  });
});

app.get('/users/game', function(req, res) {
    res.render('game', {
      title:'Game'
  });
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    // Create a new game room and notify the creator of game.
    socket.on('createGame', (data) => {
        socket.join(`room-${++rooms}`);
        socket.emit('newGame', { name: data.name, room: `room-${rooms}` });
    });

    // Connect the Player 2 to the room he requested. Show error if room full.
    socket.on('joinGame', function (data) {
        var room = io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[data.room];
        if (room && room.length === 1) {
            socket.join(data.room);
            socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('player1', {});
            socket.emit('player2', { name: data.name, room: data.room })
        } else {
            socket.emit('err', { message: 'Sorry, The room is full!' });
        }
    });

    /**
       * Handle the turn played by either player and notify the other.
       */
    socket.on('playTurn', (data) => {
        socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('turnPlayed', {
            tile: data.tile,
            room: data.room
        });
    });

    /**
       * Notify the players about the victor.
       */
    socket.on('gameEnded', (data) => {
        socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('gameEnd', data);
    });
});

//Route files
let articles = require('./routes/articles');
let users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/articles', articles);
app.use('/users', users);


//Start Sever
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server running');
});
```

Comment: What errors are showing in the browser console?  Have you defined node.js routes for all your script files?  node.js serves no files by default so you have to define routes in order to make things like `src='node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'`  and `src='/js/main2.js'` work in the browser.  My guess would be that jQuery and perhaps `main2.js` also are not loading properly into your page, thus the `$('#new').on(...)` event handler never works properly.

Comment: I have this on app.js: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); . The javascript file is on the public folder. It gives no error, nothing happens.

Comment: What do you mean "it gives no error"?  Are you looking at the debug console in the browser?  Please show us relevant server code and explain exactly  where in your file system every external file you reference in your game.pug file is located.  FYI, `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` won't make `src='node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'` work.

Comment: My bad. Here are the errors: https://i.imgur.com/KT3kLPY.png

Comment: Yeah, so you have lots of resources from that page are not loading properly including jQuery.  Also, it appears that socket.io isn't started properly on  your server either.  We need to see the relevant server code AND know exactly where every single resource you're trying to reference in your `game.pug` file is located in your server-side file system.  Then, and only then, can we help you fix your routes on the server.

Comment: Question edited

Comment: All these file locations you list are relative to what?  Are they relative to the directory of app.js?

Comment: Yes. See also my comment to your answer below. jQuery is working fine now

Comment: What port are you running your server on?  You don't show an `server.listen()` line of code so I can't see for myself?  The tick tac toe code assumes port 5000.  In `main.js`, you probably should change `const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');` to `const socket = io()` and then it will just connect to whatever host the page was loaded from.

Comment: Also, this `app.use(express.static('.'));` looks dangerous.  I think that exposes all your server files to the public which should never be done.  Your public files should be in a completely separate directory hieararchy or sub-hierarchy from your server files so your server files can never be exposed to the public.

Comment: It runs on 3000. app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server running');
});

Comment: Then, that explains why `const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');` doesn't work.  Change that to `const socket = io();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your [console screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQM0u.png), there are at least two problems here:

1. Your server-side route (if you even have one) for `script(src='node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')` is not working so jQuery never loads in the web page.  Thus, no attempt to use jQuery works.
2. Your socket.io server is not started or initialized properly on the server.

To be able to suggest fixes, we'd need to see the relevant server-side code and we'd need to know where all resources referenced in `game.pug` are located in your server-side file system (full path).  You are either missing route a definition for the jQuery file or there's an error in the route definition.

It does look like `main2.js` is loading properly, though it immediately encounters an error because of the missing jQuery.

---

FYI, using script paths like this:

```
script(src='/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')
```

is generally not considered a good practice because it exposes and ties you to a specific server-side file structure.  In general, you would do something like this instead:

```
app.use("/jquery", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/node_modules/jQuery/dist")));
```

And, then use this in the client:

```
script(src='/jquery/jquery.min.js')
```

Now, the ONLY directory you've exposed to the public is `/node_modules/jQuery/dist` and you've not created a hard link between client web pages and server-side file structure.

You would repeat that process for each `dist` directory that you need to draw from.  The way you have it now, you have granted public access to your entire `node_modules` server-side directory which is NOT something you want to do.

---

Also, when your socket.io server is working appropriately on the server, then it has a built-in route for `socket.io.js`.  You can just use this in the client:

```
script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
```

And, the socket.io server will automatically server the socket.io.js from that route.  You don't have to manually create a route for that.

---

To get socket.io working properly, change this;

```
//Start Sever
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server running');
});
```

to this:

```
//Start Sever
server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server running');
});
```

In these two lines of code, you created a web server and bound socket.io to it:

```
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

But, then with `app.listen()`, you created a different web server and started it and never started the one that socket.io is connected to.  Instead, you want to use `server.listen(...)` to start the one that you attached socket.io to.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the jQuery problem. I was missing a '/'. Now the only problem is with socket: https://i.imgur.com/83p72Ag.png

Comment: @Peplm - Made several edits to include more recommendations.

Comment: Thank you. It's showing fewer errors now: https://i.imgur.com/XurHLSS.png

Comment: @Peplm - that looks like you need to follow the advice in the last paragraph of my answer.  Your `socket.io.js` file is not loading in the client.

Comment: You mean on the game.pug file? I did that. I edited the question with the current game.pug

Comment: @Peplm - OK, the `.pug` file looks correct then.  Apparently your socket.io server is not getting started properly.  I can't see enough server code to know why that is.  FYI, you should NOT be just editing your original question like this.  This makes it impossible for ANYONE to follow what you originally asked or see how the answers actually answered a particular problem because you've destroyed the original state that we answered from.  You can add "edits" to the end of your question that show subsequent edits of the PUG file and describe them as such when you add them.

Comment: I added the full app.js

Comment: @Peplm - Did you read and understand my comment about `app.use(express.static('.'));`.  Bad, very bad.  Nothing to do with `socket.io.js`, but bad for other reasons.

Comment: @Peplm  - OK, I see the socket.io error.  See what I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: You're the best.

Comment: would you mind answering another question? It's related to this one

Comment: @Peplm - I don't know.  You'd have to post another question, share a link in a comment here and I can take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765598/create-mongoose-collection-on-express

Answer (score 2):

The code block will not working:

```
script(src='node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')
```

please try like this:

```
app.use('/scripts', 
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/dist')),
    // add some others
    );

app.use('/styles', 
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/skeleton-css/css')),
    // add some others
    );
```

On view:

```
script(src='/scripts/jquery.min.js')
link(type='text/stylesheet' href='/styles/skeleton.css')
```

And you don't need the socket-io-client module for socket client.

On your code block, if you want the socket connection of the same original host, you don't need the socket-io-client module.

if you have created the socket server using socket.io, you can include the socket.io script like this when using view template.

```
script(type='text/javascript', src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
```