# Node.js Implementing Howler

Tags: javascript, node.js, howler.js

I am very new to using the Node.js environment. I previously used a physical buzzer system in some classes at school, and am trying to make a virtual solution. I cloned the [Buffer Buzzer repository](https://github.com/bufferapp/buzzer), but I was trying to make some necessary modifications to make it more applicable for my usage, most important of which is adding sound.

I tried to implement a buzzer sound using howler, which I installed by running `npm install howler`. I then added the following code to the event listener within the [join.js](https://github.com/bufferapp/buzzer/blob/master/public/join.js) file:

```
var sound = new howler.Howl({
  src: ['buzzer.mp3']
})

sound.play();
```

However, I get the following error: `join.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: Howl is not defined`

I tried adding the following code to the [index.js](https://github.com/bufferapp/buzzer/blob/master/index.js) file (since it wouldn't work in the [join.js](https://github.com/bufferapp/buzzer/blob/master/public/join.js) file for some reason), but it still wouldn't work: `const {Howl, Howler} = require('howler')`

I thought that it would work for sure when I added `script(src='/howler/dist/howler.js')` to my index.pug file, but it still wouldn't work.

Can someone explain how this workflow works (how the [index.js](https://github.com/bufferapp/buzzer/blob/master/index.js), [join.js](https://github.com/bufferapp/buzzer/blob/master/public/join.js) and index.pug files work together) and help me figure out why the sound isn't playing?

Comment: Short long story, you need to handle the route `/howler` on the server-side, this way you will be able to load the `howler.js`. Have a look here at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49762545/javascript-code-not-running-on-pug-jade-file

Comment: @NicoVignola Sorry, I still don't understand...I have the script(src='/howler/dist/howler.js') in my client-side. What do I need to add to the server-side and how I get this to link up with the client side?

Comment: in the `index.js` file, you need to add `app.use(
  "/howler",
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/node_modules/howler/dist"))
)`. This way, `script(src='/howler/dist/howler.js')` will work, and the `js` file will be loaded correctly.